# OMP for nested loops in VS2017

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, nested-loops

I am new on using **OpenMP 2.0** along with **MSVC++ 2017**. I'm working with a *big data structure* (referenced as *bigMap*) so I need to distribute the workload when iterating on it in the **best possible way**. My attempt for doing so is:

```
std::map<int, std::set<std::pair<double, double>>> bigMap;
///thousands of values are added here

int k;
int max_threads = omp_get_max_threads();
omp_set_num_threads(max_threads);
#pragma omp parallel default(none) private(k)
{
  #pragma omp for
  for(k = kMax; k > kMin; k--)
  {
    for (auto& myPair : bigMap[k])
    {
      int pthread = omp_get_thread_num();
      std::cout << "Thread " << pthread << std::endl;
      for (auto& item : myPair)
      {
         #pragma omp critical
         myMap[k-1].insert(std::make_pair(item, 0));
       }
    }
}
```

The output for "pthread" is always "0" and the execution time is the same as for single-thread (so I assume no new threads are being created).
Why this code doesn't work and which **OMP *directives* / *clauses* / *sections*** are wrong??

**UPDATE:**

OMP is now working, but the code below is not working as expected:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)
for (int i = 0; i < map_size; ++i) {
    #pragma omp critical
    bigMap[i] = std::set<int>();
}
bigMap[1] = { 10, 100, 1000 };

int i;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) num_threads(8)
for (i = thread_num; i < map_size; i += thread_count)
{
    for (auto it = bigMap[i].begin(); it != bigMap[i].end(); ++it)
    {
        int elem = *it;
        bigMap[i + 1].insert(elem);
    }
}
```

I expect the 3 elements from bigMap[1] to be inserted across all entries of bigMap, instead, they're inserted only once, for bigMap[2], why??

Comment: Have you tried the same code under clang or gcc?  I’d be pretty wary of MSVC’s implementation at this point. It’s old, and MS is unusually close-lipped about it, even for them.

Comment: std::cout will be serialized and you have serialized the inner loop by adding the critical, so you can't expect a parallel speedup.  If you would reverse the direction of the outer omp for, there would be no reason why the Microsoft OpenMP should fall short (although it hasn't been upgraded since VS2005).

Comment: @zzxyz, I didn't because I'm bounded to MSVC for this, otherwise I'd be happy to use stuff available for OMP versions > 3 such as tasks and custom reductions. So I must figure out how to make it work on MSVC...

Comment: @tim18 I didn't notice *std::cout* would be serialized but in fact it is, even if it's added just for verification. Regarding the reversing of the *outer omp for*, I didn't get your point, do you mean that if I reverse it back it will perform better? Thanks

Comment: MS has their own library. I’d probably use that for MS and use the latest for everything else. parallel_for and whatnot on the MS end. That said, there could just be something wrong with your code I missed.

Comment: @zzxyz At first I tried Microsoft's concurrency library <ppl.h>, but it doesn't work for me because I'm building a backend CLR library ("concurrency is not supported when compiling with /clr"). Surprisingly, OMP works with /clr (MS forbids use of PPL but allows OMP...). Now OMP is working, but not as desired, I updated my question with the current code.

Answer (score 0):

Little bug....

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)
for (int i = 0; i < map_size; ++i) {
    #pragma omp critical
    bigMap[i] = std::set<int>();
}
bigMap[1] = { 10, 100, 1000 };

int i;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) num_threads(8)
for (i = thread_num; i < map_size; i += thread_count)
{
    //here you loop on bigMap[i] which is empty execpt for i==1.
    //for (auto it = bigMap[i].begin(); it != bigMap[i].end(); ++it)
    for (auto it = bigMap[1].begin(); it != bigMap[1].end(); ++it)
    {
        int elem = *it;
        bigMap[i + 1].insert(elem);
    }
}
```

Maybe you miss understand what static means.